# How to change SSH port number on azure hdinsight spark machine

Tags: azure, ssh, apache-spark, azure-hdinsight

I spun up a HDInsight spark cluster. However I'd like to change the `ssh` port of the `<cluster>-ssh.azurehdinsight.net` head.

I changed the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and added `Port xyz` and restarted the `ssh` service

But still cannot access it through the proposed port. I checked `iptables` and didn't see any blocking rules.

Anyone?

Comment: Have you added the proper Endpoint in Azure Portal?

Comment: There is no endpoint for hdinsight spark instance unfortunately :( or I can not find it ;)